# How to use multi process workers in fluentd configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, fluentd

I am uploading some log file to `elasticsearch`. Total log files I have is `56` and thus I have `56` `source` and `match` in the `fluentd.conf`. Because of huge amount of data I think 1 worker of fluentd will not be able to handle the traffic effectively and thus I am planning to run multiple workers.

I am referring to this [doc](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/multi-process-workers) where it shows to use below in fluent.conf file:

```
<system>
  workers 4
</system>
```

But when I use above, it do not run and is always in exit state. Can anyone please tell me how to run multiple workers of fluentd. Thanks

Comment: Please share the fluentd's logs.